# Websphere liberty profile error: 404 SRVE0190E

Tags: java, servlets, websphere-8, websphere-liberty

What could be the reason for the error: `Error 404: SRVE0190E: File not found: /SimpleServletPath`

I am deploying in websphere liberty profile server.

I can't reach my admin console [login page](http://1242.22.22.22:9080/ibm/console)

I can reach my welcome page on my websphere liberty profile server but can't do so after creating a servlet. That's when the above 404 error comes up.

There are similar posts online that advice to change `com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.invokefilterscompatibility=true` . I can't find how to set this parameter because I can't hit the websphere admin console login.

I installed websphere through eclipse marketplace.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
<display-name>ServletExplore</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>

</welcome-file-list>
    </web-app
```

Comment: It would be helpful to see your web.xml and/or the @Servlet declarations from your source.

Comment: Also, Liberty doesn't have an admin console. All config is done with the server.xml, which is designed to be compact and human readable. Are you deploying using 'Run as' in the Eclipse IDE?

Comment: Holly, Yes yes. I'm running it in the eclipse IDE. I'm wondering if it's a URL mapping issue now because I had first created an index.html file/Welcome file then created a servlet example: The URL was supposed to be http://localhost:9080/Welcome page/Servlettest/. I just created the servlet page without index.html and it worked. Now "http://localhost:9080/Servlettest"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, your app's context root will default to the name of the application. You can change it (including setting it to /) by looking at the server on the Servers tab and editing its configuration. You can make changes in the GUI or directly in the server.xml.

If your app is called my app, I suspect localhost:9080/myapp/SimpleServletPath is where your servlet is currently living.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using annotation @WebServlet in your servlet, but you have web.xml file. Remove web.xml file from your project and run again.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).